# Show different View or ViewController when internet connection missing

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

I would like to show a different view or `UIViewController` instead of my `UITableView` when there is no Internet connection instead of an alert. I am using `Reachability Class` but there must be something wrong as nothing is happening when there is no connection:

```
func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {
    let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

    if reachability.isReachable() {

    } 
    else {

    var connectionProblemView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("connectionProblemView") as! ConnectionProblemViewController  
    self.presentViewController(connectionProblemView, animated: true, completion: nil)  

   /*   var alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()

        THIS WAS WORKING FINE
  */      
    }
}
```

Comment: Add  `NSLog` or `println` statements or breakpoints to check if the code is reached and what `connectionProblemView` is at runtime

Comment: @luk2302 THANKS...  I don't why I didn't  try that before posting the question.  I was testing the app on the simulator and I had switched the wifi off on my computer thinking that it was enough to simulate the condition but it wasn't. It is working on the device